# Getting constants from another file in Perl

Tags: perl, constants, config

I'm trying to extract some constants from a Perl file which I've defined in file A.pm

```
package A;

use constant ERROR_ID_MAP => [
    PLAYBACK_ERROR => {
         defaultMessage => "Sorry there was an error with a playback",
         errorCode => 0,
    },
    PURCHASE_ERROR => {
         defaultMessage => "Sorry, we've encountered a problem with purchasing. Please try again.",
         errorCode => 2123,
    },
];
```

and so on...

then in package B, I want to get that error file somehow. My thought was to get it like:

```
sub getErrorMap {
   my ($self) = @_;
   my $map = A::ERROR_ID_MAP;

   # Iterate through the array / hash and get the error's default message etc.
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The other option is to make package A into a class and perhaps return the constant? (In package A):

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;

    my $self;

    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}

sub getErrorConstants {
   my $self = @_;
   return ERROR_ID_MAP;
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this perhaps to just get all the data inside ERROR_ID_MAP without going through this trouble, so we almost treat package A as a configuration file of sorts?

NOTE - hopefully there's not too many errors in the code above that will take away from the point of the question.

Comment: `A` and `B` are poorly chosen names to use in examples because there is a module called `B` which is part of the Perl core. `Foo` and `Bar`, or perhaps `AAAA` and `BBBB` are better example names.

Comment: @tobyink: They're poor choices of package names for reasons other than that they already exist in published libraries: they are completely meaningless! At least in the case of [the `B` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/B) it stands for *Backend*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write a module, say `Definitions.pm`, that uses [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/module/Exporter), like this

**Definitions.pm**

```
package Definitions;

use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Exporter';

our @EXPORT_OK = qw/ ERROR_ID_MAP /;

use constant ERROR_ID_MAP => [
    PLAYBACK_ERROR => {
         defaultMessage => "Sorry there was an error with a playback",
         errorCode => 0,
    },
    PURCHASE_ERROR => {
         defaultMessage => "Sorry, we've encountered a problem with purchasing. Please try again.",
         errorCode => 2123,
    },
];
```

Then you can just `use Definitions` and specify the constants that you want to import in your main code, like this

**main.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Definitions qw/ ERROR_ID_MAP /;

use Data::Dump;

dd ERROR_ID_MAP;
```

**output**

```
[
  "PLAYBACK_ERROR",
  {
    defaultMessage => "Sorry there was an error with a playback",
    errorCode => 0,
  },
  "PURCHASE_ERROR",
  {
    defaultMessage => "Sorry, we've encountered a problem with purchasing. Please try again.",
    errorCode => 2123,
  },
]
```

Answer (score 6):

While [@Borodin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27389664/100754) may look like it is doing what you want, be aware that there is nuance to `constant.pm` as the following example demonstrates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::XS;

use constant X => [ { test => 1 }];

print Dump X;

X->[0]{test} = 3;

print Dump X;
```

#### Output

```
$ ./zxc.pl
---
- test: 1
---
- test: 3
```

`use constant X => [ ... ]` means the constant subroutine always returns the same reference. However, you can manipulate the elements to which that reference points. If you truly want to export constants, consider using [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast):

#### Definitions.pm

```
package Definitions;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Const::Fast;
use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT = qw();
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( $ERROR_ID_MAP );

const our $ERROR_ID_MAP => [
    PLAYBACK_ERROR => {
        defaultMessage => "Sorry there was an error with a playback",
        errorCode => 0,
    },
    PURCHASE_ERROR => {
        defaultMessage => "Sorry, we've encountered a problem with purchasing. Please try again.",
        errorCode => 2123,
    },
];
```

#### main.pl

```
!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML::XS;
use Definitions qw( $ERROR_ID_MAP );

print Dump $ERROR_ID_MAP;

$ERROR_ID_MAP->[1]{errorCode} = 3;
```

#### Output:

```
---
- PLAYBACK_ERROR
- defaultMessage: Sorry there was an error with a playback
  errorCode: 0
- PURCHASE_ERROR
- defaultMessage: Sorry, we've encountered a problem with purchasing. Please try again.
  errorCode: 2123
Modification of a read-only value attempted at ./main.pl line 11.
```

Notice how an attempt to change an element of the data structure to which `$ERROR_ID_MAP` refers causes a helpful exception.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to put

```
use A;
```

in `B.pm`

Comment: Hi Sputnik. You're correct, though I feel you're missing the overall question which is "Is there a more friendly way to do what I've demonstrated that I don't know about?"

Comment: Once the module `A` has been loaded, either `A::ERROR_ID_MAP` or `A->ERROR_ID_MAP` will work. You can even do `my $class = "A"; $class->ERROR_ID_MAP`. Of these three choices the first is usually preferred because it can be optimized by the Perl compiler.