# Iterate through global hash constants in perl

Tags: perl, hash, constants

I have a hash of constants I want to iterate through in another file. So I have a file containing the global constants:

```
use base qw (Exporter);

use constant ERROR_CONFIG => {
    ERROR_STRING => {
         errorCode => 1234,
         default => 'Some default text here',
    },
    ERROR_STRING => {
         errorCode => 12345,
         default => 'More text',
    },
};
```

So I seem to have access to it in the other file, but I'm unable to iterate through it.

I want to iterate over every key (ERROR_STRING)

Then I want to iterate over it and push into an arrayref, but Perl doesn't seem to see it as a hash. I tried the following but it didn't work when I dumped out the result:

```
my @array = ();
$stringsRef = \@array;

my %config = &ERROR_CONFIG;

foreach my $key (keys %config) {
  push @$stringsRef, {name => 'ERROR_MESSAGE_' . $key};
}

Data::Dumper::Dumper($stringsArray);
```

I don't seem to get any result here, only an error, even if I try putting &ERROR_CONFIG straight in instead of %config.

Comment: `use warnings;` might be helpful.

Comment: Wonder if we could just make a pop up for any question tagged `perl` - "hey, did you `use strict; use warnings`? If not, please go do that first. And then format your code.

Comment: I'm using warnings and strict.

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in the definition of constant. You must ave `=>` instead of `=`:

```
use constant ERROR_CONFIG => {
#                  here __^^
    ERROR_STRING => {
         errorCode => 1234,
         default => 'Some default text here',
    },
    ERROR_STRING => {
         errorCode => 12345,
         default => 'More text',
    },
};
```

and you can't have twice the same key in a hash. I guess you want an array:

```
use constant ERROR_CONFIG => [
    ERROR_STRING => {
         errorCode => 1234,
         default => 'Some default text here',
    },
    ERROR_STRING => {
         errorCode => 12345,
         default => 'More text',
    },
];
```

Comment: Doesn't that make you a constant array of not-constant references?

Comment: @Sobrique: Yes, pretty much. It creates a subroutine `ERROR_CONFIG` that returns an *anonymous array* that has the specified contents. It's like a C `const struct *`.

Comment: Referring to the 'same key in the same hash' comment, they are unique keys, where I have about 15 different error messages, all with unique keys in place of ERROR_STRING.

Comment: At which point I'd be wondering - if you can modify elements of your constant structure, is it actually necessary to make one, rather than - for example - just defining a hash.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
use base qw (Exporter);
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant ERROR_CONFIG = {
    ERROR_STRING => {
        errorCode => 1234,
        default   => 'Some default text here',
    },
    ERROR_STRING => {
        errorCode => 12345,
        default   => 'More text',
    },
};
```

Gives me:
`Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at  line 14, at EOF`.

I think this would be your problem. I don't actually think you can define a constant like this - a hash of hashes is effectively a list of references. The references might be constant, but the target of it might well not be.

But more importantly - you're trying to duplicate your hash keys, and that's simply never going to work either. You cannot have two hash elements called 'ERROR_STRING'.

As noted by the other contributor - changing it to '=>' works, but you still get a constant array of not-constant elements:

```
 print ERROR_CONFIG->[0],"\n";
 print Dumper ERROR_CONFIG;

 ERROR_CONFIG->[0] = "wibble";

 print Dumper ERROR_CONFIG;
```

`&ERROR_CONFIG` isn't going to work either. `&` doesn't dereference in perl, it's the sigil for a subroutine. `ERROR_CONFIG` isn't a sub so it isn't going to work.

Personally I'd suggest either:

```
use base qw (Exporter);
use strict;
use warnings;

our %error_config = (
    1234  => 'Some default text',
    12345 => 'More text',
);

foreach my $key (keys %error_config) {
    print "$key $error_config{$key}\n";
}
```

And just accept your hash isn't a constant. Or if you really need to to not be changable, either use `Hash::Util` and `lock_hash_recurse` or instead, make it a 'private' hash and use accessors.

```
{
    my %private_hash = (
        1234  => 'Some default text',
        12345 => 'More text',
    );

    sub get_errors {
        return %private_hash;
    }
}

my %error_codes = get_errors();

print Dumper \%error_codes
```

(If you really want, you could use some accessor subs to change the private doodad, but you seem to be copying your constant in to a not-constant anyway, so it didn't seem necessary).

Comment: The code he's using is mine from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388828). The solitary `=` should be a `=>`

Comment: Yes he's right, there was a mistake in my answer. I'll modify.

Comment: I suppose the question has now changed though to - Are you able to define a hash of constants the way I have above and use them in the context of a hash?

Comment: No, the question remains: What are you trying to accomplish? How important is it that someone using your hash is faced with readonly values?

Comment: They are constants. Every unique error string has a code and default value that will never change.

Comment: Yes, but could you just put them into a normal hash?